# How to find a key word in function?

Tags: php, regex

Thanks for your help first!

I have some jscripts like:

```
var id="001";

var name="Jerry";
...

function f1() {
  ...
  var qid="q1";
  ...
}

...
var qid="aaabbb";
...

function f2(){
  ...
  var myid="q1";
  ...
}

...
```

I want to use regular expression to get the names of function that contains key word "q1". Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Do you have the entire script in a string?

Comment: Probably can't be done with regex. :-( Good luck!

Comment: no, there is not. The programming languages are context-free and the regex process just regular languages.

Comment: this isnt what a regex is for

Comment: you may want to try lexer / tokenizer for this job

Answer (score 2):

Functions can be defined within other functions in JavaScript, so using regular expressions to try to solve this problem is impossible. Sorry :-(

Also, the problem is underspecified. What function name do you want in a case like this?

```
function outerFunction(x, y) {
    var innerFunction = function(z) {
        return {
            firstProperty: function() {
                return "q1";
            }
        };
    };
}
```

See? Three different ways to declare a function. How would you create a solution general enough to know the "correct" (most relevant) function name for cases like this?

Comment: It was downvoted before I added the code sample, but even so, I wish I knew. :-(

Comment: Although you made a valid point, you were kinda a buzz kill. Seems like the downvote is gone now

Comment: @Mikhail: Being a buzz kill is NOT a proper reason for a downvote.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Oh I fully agree with you. Thinking outside the box deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
/^function ([^(]*?)\((?=(?:[^\n]|\n[^}])*("q1")).*?^}/ms
```

Note that this does not match "q1" when it is outside of a function, or function names that don't have "q1" inside.  For each match the first group will be the function name and the second group will be "q1".

See it in action: http://rubular.com/r/xQwro38DUO

Here is an explanation:

```
$regex = <<<END
/
    ^function[ ]         # start looking when a line starts with function
    ([^(]*?)\(           # capture the function name into group 1
    (?=                  # start a lookahead
      (?:[^\n]|\n[^}])*  # consume characters until a line starts with '}'
      ("q1")             # or until we find "q1" (and place it in group 2)
    )                    # end lookahead
    .*?^}                # consume until end of function (optional)
/msx                     # m and s flags for consuming multiple line handling
END;
```

Comment: This is great, and thanks for using rubular :-D I forgot about lookahead. You don't need to group `("q1")` separately. removing the `()` will result only in the function name.

Comment: Hi F.J, It doesn't work when q1 is removed from function f1. It gets f1 instead of f2:

var id="001";

var name="Jerry";
...

function f1() {
  ...
  var qid="q2";
  ...
}

...
var qid="aaabbb";
...

function f2(){
  ...
  var myid="q1";
  ...
}

...

Comment: @JerryLu, it seems to be matching the beginning of f1, and the end of f2. It may be simpler to first split your string by "function" into an array of functions, and just search each cell for "q1"

Comment: This won't work if the user indents any of their functions, either through nesting or simply because of a typo. And as I've explained in my answer, not all functions are declared with `function someFunctionName()`.

Comment: @JerryLu - Just edited so that it no longer has that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex that seems to work for me:

```
(function(.*)\(.*|\n*"q1")
```

and here's how I tested it:

http://rubular.com/r/APPNRR54oW

Comment: This is actually too greedy. I'll update the answer when I fine tune this